# What is the right way to do client-side routing on a single-page-app?

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing, single-page-application

I am creating a single-page-app (SPA) on my local machine, but a few levels down from the document root. So, for example, my index page would be at `http://localhost/projects/foo/index.html`.

I'm using [Davis.js](http://davisjs.com/) to do client-side routing with the history API, and it recommends using absolute URLs for its routes. E.g. `<a href="/hello/world">` triggers the `/hello/world` route.

This is a problem, because when you click that link residing on `http://localhost/projects/foo/index.html`, it changes the URL to `http://localhost/hello/world`, which is obviously not right, even though the app continues on like normal (because you never actually left the page). Refresh the page, though, and you'll get a 404 error, because the file `http://localhost/hello/world` doesn't exist.

Using relative links, like `<a href="hello/world">` gets closer to the mark. Clicking that link changes the URL to `http://localhost/projects/foo/hello/world`, but does *not* trigger the `/hello/world` route. Click that same link again, and you'll find yourself at `http://localhost/projects/foo/hello/hello/world` (double hello). Again, not desired behavior.

Now, what's going on is that Davis is matching routes from the root of the domain, so `/hello/world` will only trigger when the url is `http://somewhere.tld/hello/world`. But even if I was serving directly out of the document root, there's still the problem that `/hello/world` *doesn't actually exist*.

At the moment, my current solution is forcing Davis to use hash-based routing instead of path-based: `http://localhost/projects/foo/index.html#/hello/world`. This works 100% as expected, because the browser will always load `index.html` and Davis will always see the `/hello/world`. Additionally, links containing that hash fragment will always work, provided the user has Javascript turned on. (I'm not worried about that case)

One solution I can see is to have a base URL of `http://localhost/projects/foo/`, have a server rewrite all requests in that directory to `index.html`, and have all links and routes point to and match the base url + fragment (like `http://localhost/projects/foo/hello/world`). So technically, all those URLs *do* exist, they just all point to the same file. This, however, requires that **(a)** a server capable of URL-rewriting serves the SPA (the url-hash solution doesn't even require a server, just a browser) and **(b)** the SPA keep track of "where" it is relative to the document root (which to me is a *very* bad thing).

So my question is, what is the **right** way to do client-side routing, agnostic to the app's location on the server, and preferably without requiring server-side technology other than static hosting.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're looking for a workaround for your development environment or if the app would really be deployed onto a server with those paths.

Comment: @steveax - I'm looking for the best way to do client-side routing on an SPA, agnostic to its location on the server, and preferably without requiring anything server-side except static hosting.

Comment: This seems specific the the library used. I'm not familiar with Davis.js, but from a quick look at the docs, it appears that you can use [scope](http://olivernn.github.com/davis.js/docs/#scope) to prepend a global path for yor app.

Comment: @steveax - That's not really the library's problem. The problem with appending the global/base path is that now the app needs to know where it is in relation to the document root. If I move the app, I need to change the code.

Comment: Yep. Applications != a bunch of linked web pages and they usually expect to be at the document root.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar experience with single page apps and client-side routing.

After considering this problem a little, I eventually realized that in the interest of SEO, you will want to actually have your server render the content at the absolute urls that Davis is suggesting.  That way, the Google crawler can actually continue to crawl through your website as if it were not a single page app.

If you say you can't do any server-side technology, then the problem will be much more difficult.  The solutions you have presented all seem reasonable.

You may also wish to read on this link about [Google's specification for its crawler](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to have whatever client side routes you are defining with Davis also be available on the server.  So if you have a client side route of `/foo/bar` then the server should ideally be able to respond sensibly to the same route.

This is often simpler than it sounds and doesn't have to involve a lot of duplication if you are using a language agnostic templating language such as mustache.

If this is not possible then there are workarounds so that the server returns something other than a 404 for your client side only routes.  However these always feel like workarounds rather than solutions to me. Obviously the answer depends on what kind of application you are building.

As for using Davis with relative routes, I admit that is something that I've never used and so can't say how well supported it would be.  There isn't anything in particular in the design of Davis that would prevent it from working.

However I've just been playing around with the pushState api in the browser here and it does seem to have some weirdness with relative paths.